# Cast $1 in a regex replace

Tags: c#, regex

I want to add 1 to the last int of the list, using regex in c#:
"10, 20, 30" -> "10, 20, 31"

This is to test the $1 is working as expected:

```
Regex.Replace("10, 20, 30", @"(\d+)$", "-$1-")
10, 20, -30-
```

This is to test the cast is working as expected:

```
Regex.Replace("10, 20, 30", @"(\d+)$", (int.Parse("30")+1).ToString())
10, 20, 31
```

And the final complete code is not working:

```
Regex.Replace("10, 20, 30", @"(\d+)$", (int.Parse("$1")+1).ToString())
input string was not in a correct format
```

Why is the $1 not interpreted when casting ?

Comment: Because `"$1"` doesn't have any relationship with the regular expression, the compiler isn't magical, if you want to grab the matched text from the `Regex.Replace` call, you will have to do it. Try this: `Regex.Replace("10, 20, 30", @"(\d+)$", ma => (int.Parse(ma.Groups["1"].Value)+1)`

Comment: Correct. Regex.Replace("10, 20, 30", @"(\d+)$",ma => (int.Parse(ma.Value)+1).ToString()) is working.

Comment: but $1 is the first captured group, and it gives the expected result in my first example. What is the difference with the last example ?

Comment: "$1" is only a group when inside the `Regex.Replace` call, but `int.Parse` have no relationship with `Regex.Replace`, so it just gets the string `"$1"` and cannot parse that.

Comment: The second is using a callback function. So it passes `$1` literally in.

Comment: Your code is literally equivalent to this: `string replacement = int.Parse("$1")+1).ToString(); Regex.Replace("10, 20, 30", @"(\d+)$", replacement)`

Comment: That's clear now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen gives the correct answer. See question comments for details.

```
Regex.Replace("10, 20, 30", @"(\d+)$",ma => (int.Parse(ma.Value)+1).ToString())
10, 20, 31
```